# Should this code fail to compile in C++17?

Tags: c++, clang, c++17, boost-variant

I was updating a project to use C++17 and found a few instances where code that followed this pattern was causing a compile error on recent versions of clang:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

struct vis : public boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    void operator()(int) const { }
};

int main()
{
    boost::variant<int> v = 0;
    boost::apply_visitor(vis{}, v);
}
```

[Using clang v8.0 in C++17 mode, this fails with the following error](https://godbolt.org/z/jlStVD):

```
<source>:11:30: error: temporary of type 'boost::static_visitor<void>' has protected destructor
    boost::apply_visitor(vis{}, v);
                             ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/libs/boost_1_64_0/boost/variant/static_visitor.hpp:53:5: note: declared protected here
    ~static_visitor() = default;
```

However, [it compiles cleanly in C++14 mode](https://godbolt.org/z/TVPqNJ). I found that if I change the brace initialization `vis{}` to parentheses `vis()`, then it compiles correctly in both modes. Every version of gcc that I've tried allows both variants in C++17 mode.

Is this a correct change in behavior from C++14 to C++17, or is this a clang bug? If it is correct, why is it now invalid in C++17 (or maybe it always was, but clang just allows it in earlier standard revisions)?

Comment: Boost [fixed](https://github.com/boostorg/variant/commit/dd728220b00772cee5d3aea5850a2bb09eecc66b#diff-e8948f8833a40a3c873b7f8d4ff5f9d7) this in 1.70. It's also discussed [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D53860).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

clang is correct here. Here's a reduced example:

```
struct B {
protected:
    B() { }
};

struct D : B { };

auto d = D{};
```

In C++14, `D` is *not* an aggregate because it has a base class, so `D{}` is "normal" (non-aggregate) initialization which invokes `D`'s default constructor, which in turn invokes `B`'s default constructor. This is fine, because `D` has access to `B`'s default constructor.

In C++17, the definition of aggregate was widened - base classes are now allowed (as long as they're non-`virtual`). `D` is now an aggregate, which means that `D{}` is aggregate initialization. And in aggregate-initialization, this means that we (the caller) are initializing all the subobjects - including the base class subobject. But we do *not* have access to `B`'s constructor (it is `protected`), so we cannot invoke it, so it is ill-formed.

---

Fear not, the fix is easy. Use parentheses:

```
auto d = D();
```

This goes back to invoking `D`'s default constructor as before.

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for: the widened definition of aggregate is the culprit.

Comment: Is clang right to be right? What is the accessibility context of the subobject initializer? There is a core language issue about that: [issue #2244](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2244). As a coder, I would prefer that name accessibility checks for [dcl.init.aggr/5.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5.1) and [dcl.init.aggr/5.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#5.2) are done, in both cases, in the context of the aggregate.

Comment: I heard that parentheses and braces are unified in C++20. Does that affect the validity of the fix?

Comment: @L.F. No, it does not. `D()` being [value initialization](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.4) precedes the [new bullet](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2.2).

Comment: @Oliv I think clang is right to be right. I don't know what the accessibility direction is.

Comment: Slightly wrong reduction. The issue in C++17 is the dtor (`static_visitor` is a C++17 aggregate itself, so the protectedness of the ctor doesn't matter). In C++20, both are problems and the boost fix (which fixed the dtor only) will break again, which makes this a nice example of the C++20 OMG-these-contrived-examples-are-so-surprising-we-must-fix-it change breaking things.

Comment: @T.C. gcc and clang both complain about [the ctor](https://godbolt.org/z/G7sq0C)?

Comment: They both complain about the ctor on your (slightly wrong) reduced example.

Comment: @T.C. Oh I see what you mean now. I guess it's a slightly different problem, with the same underlying reason.