# Does this code result in a materialized base prvalue, and should it compile?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, destructor, compiler-generated

The following code compiles in gcc 9.1 [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/RBwEN3) but not clang 8 [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/m-AoSX):

```
class A {
protected:
    ~A() = default;
};

class B final : public A {
};

int main() {
    auto b = B{};
}
```

Clang's error:

```
<source>:10:16: error: temporary of type 'A' has protected destructor
    auto b = B{};
               ^
<source>:3:5: note: declared protected here
    ~A() = default;
    ^
```

Which is correct and why?

Comment: (slightly) simpler version with the same behavior: https://godbolt.org/z/VUBXqd Based on that, I tend to think it's a bug, since the same thing without explicit default initialization compiles OK. (`B b{}` fails, while `B b` succeeds)

Comment: Related: https://reviews.llvm.org/D53860

Comment: Is `final` important? EDIT: it appears that it isn't

Comment: Clang should be correct. This is due to aggregate. Try `auto b =B();` see if it compiles.  is a dup to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367480/should-this-code-fail-to-compile-in-c17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Clang is correct in rejecting the code.

In `auto b = B{};` we have an aggregate initialization, which happens directly in `main` function. So this function must be able to call destructors of `B` subtypes in case of exception occurrence during the initialization.

A quotation from N4861 (the last C++20 draft), [[dcl.init.aggr]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.aggr#8):

> The destructor for each element of class type is potentially invoked
> from the context where the aggregate initialization occurs. [ Note:
> This provision ensures that destructors can be called for
> fully-constructed subobjects in case an exception is thrown. — end
> note ]

Just to be complete, a quote from [[class.dtor]/15](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.dtor#15):

> [...] A program is ill-formed if a destructor that is potentially
> invoked is deleted or not accessible from the context of the
> invocation.

Comment: N4868 is a better approximation to C++20, partly because of subclause reorganization.

Comment: I think the question is the same in C++17 and C++20. At least the compilers issue the same errors in both modes. But in C++20 the standard clarifies better this behavior.

Comment: Sure—I wasn’t claiming anything was different, just trying to get people to use the best “C++20” as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the clarifications in the comments;
Since C++17, `B{}` is aggregate even though it is derived from `A`, so a temporary `A` will be created for the aggregate init by the user which has no access to the `dtor`. So clang is correct in rejecting the compile. The standard:

> [no virtual, private, or protected (since C++17) base classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)

However using `()` will work as the standard says.

The `dtor` of the base can be public or protected.

> A common guideline is that a destructor for a base class must be
>   either public and virtual or protected and nonvirtual

[see the guideline of standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor)

In contrast with C++11, where the expression `B()` is a `prvalue`, and `auto b = B();` is a move-construction and the move will likely get elided, In C++17, there is no move. The `prvalue` is not moved from. This is value-initializing `B()` and is exactly equivalent to:

```
B();
```

[Value Categories in C++17](https://medium.com/@barryrevzin/value-categories-in-c-17-f56ae54bccbe)

[Should this code fail to compile in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56367566/10933809)

Comment: This does not address the issue, which is more complex and involves the rules surrounding guaranteed copy elision. It's not about coding style conventions. Furthermore, a wiki is not the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The guideline confirms that deriving from a class that has a protected dtor is allowed, which was what oblivion (and I) understood that Q was.

Comment: @curiousguy, @oblivion I intended the question not as whether deriving from a class with a protected destructor is generally allowed, but whether this particular example is allowed, and the compilers disagree. The comments suggest that it should not be allowed, and that clang is correct to reject it. Also, `B{}` is aggregate initialization here, not value initialization.

Comment: @JeffGarrett For many ppl it isn't clear at first what *could* even be ill formed in the example, and how the aggregate init syntax matters! The Q doesn't even say "aggregate" (not does the error msg).

Comment: Oh yes for sure. It seems counterintuitive. I probably should've said aggregate, but I wasn't sure I wasn't missing something. Initialization in C++ is complex. :)

Comment: @JeffGarrett I updated the answer. Seems the standard clearly mentioned you cannot have protected dtor.

Comment: cppreference isn't "the standard."