# "temporary of type 'A' has protected destructor", but its type is B

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17, access-levels

In the following code, compiled with Clang 8.0.0+ and `-std=c++17`, creating a derived class instance using `B{}` gives an error `error: temporary of type 'A' has protected destructor`. Why is `A` appearing in this message when the temporary has type `B` (and thus should have a public destructor)?

https://godbolt.org/z/uOzwYa

```
class A {
protected:
    A() = default;
    ~A() = default;
};

class B : public A {
// can also omit these 3 lines with the same result
public:
    B() = default;
    ~B() = default;
};

void foo(const B&) {}

int main() {

    // error: temporary of type 'A' has protected destructor
    foo(B{});
    //    ^

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For me this compiles in clang with no errors. What version of clang are you using?

Comment: What does it say if you run `clang --version`?

Comment: The error appeared in clang 8.0.0: https://godbolt.org/z/uOzwYa (no error with 6 or 7)

Comment: That's whack.  I'm seeing the same thing with Apple LLVM 10.0.1.

Comment: Probably because `B` inherits from `A`, which has a protected destructor.

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56367480/2069064)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a subtle issue of [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) before C++20.

Before C++20, `B` (and `A`) are [aggregate types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Explanation):

(emphasis mine)

> no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (**explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed**) (since C++17) (until C++20)

Then

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members `and bases (since C++17)` or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members `and bases (since C++17)` are initialized `by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14)` by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates).

So `B{}` constructs a temporary object via aggregate initialization, which will initialize the base subobject directly with empty list, i.e. perform aggregate initialization to construct the `A` base subobject. Note that the constructor of `B` is bypassed. The problem is that in such context, the `protected` desctructor can't be called to destroy the directly constructed base subobject of type `A`. (It doesn't complain about the `protected` constructor because it's bypassed by the aggregate initialization of `A` too.)

You can change it to `foo(B());` to avoid aggregate initialization; `B()` performs [value-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), the temporary object will be initialized by `B`'s constructor, then anything is fine.

BTW since C++20 you code will work fine.

> no user-declared or inherited constructors (since C++20)

`B` (and `A`) are not aggregate types again. `B{}` performes [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), and then the temporary object is initialized by `B`'s constructor; the effect is just same as `B()`.